# when the incoming url is a query, in which function does WP begin to work with it?

Tags: query-string, wp-parse-args

I need to debug a problem with filters I have in place. they're affecting any url that includes a query; eg, `http://my.domain.hk/?attachment=1`. does anyone know in which function WP begins to work with this kind of url, one that includes a query?

cheers,
Gregory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any url that doesn't point to a file/directory that actually exists is redirected (by .htaccess) to the `index.php` in the root of your WordPress install.

`index.php` is what actually loads WordPress and its settings etc. It then calls the function [`wp();`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/functions.php#L1561), which is responsible for initialising WordPress' actually handling of the request.

`wp()` is little more than a wrapper for the [`wp-class` class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/class-wp.php). In particular, the [`main()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L492) method:

```
function main($query_args = '') {
    $this->init();
    $this->parse_request($query_args);
    $this->send_headers();
    $this->query_posts();
    $this->handle_404();
    $this->register_globals();
    do_action_ref_array('wp', array(&$this));
}
```

The [`parse_request()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L110) method turns the request (handling pretty permalinks, internal rewrites and extra arguments -**i.e. interpreting `?attachment=1`**) into '`query_vars`' (variables concerning the query). The [`query_posts()`](http://query_posts%28%29) *method* then turns that into an actual `WP_Query` object (the globals `$wp_the_query` and `$wp_query` - which are [initialised in wp-settings.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-settings.php#L220)).

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. the phrase 'internal rewrites' helped me. I found what I was looking for in redirect_canonical(). cheers.